# extending burn-in period after JAGS model has been run in runjags for R

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, runjags

The `runjags` package for R is fantastic. The parallel capabilities and the ability to use the `extend.jags` function make my life so much better. However, sometimes, after I run a model, I realize the burn-in phase should be have been longer. How can I trim extra samples out of my `run.jags` output, so I can re-estimate my parameter distributions and check for convergence?

```
jags.object <- run.jags(model, n.chains=3, data=data, monitor =c('a','b'), sample=10000)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this within runjags unfortunately, so you will have to work with the underlying mcmc.list object - something like:

```
library('coda')
mcmc.object <- as.mcmc.list(jags.object)
niter(mcmc.object)
windowed.object <- window(mcmc.object, start=10001)
summary(windowed.object)
```

Note that the start (and end) arguments of window.mcmc include the burn in phase, so if you have 5000 burn in + 10000 samples then this code gives you iterations 10001:15000

However, a window method for the runjags class would be a good idea, and hopefully something that will appear soon!

[It may also be worth noting that you can use the combine=FALSE argument with extend.jags to drop the entire first lot of iterations, but this obviously requires re-sampling new iterations so not exactly what you want.]

Also - thanks for the kind words about the package - feedback and feature suggestions are always welcome at https://sourceforge.net/p/runjags/forum/general/  :)

Comment: Thanks Matt! this will certainly trim it up as desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trim off extra samples from the posterior distribution you can subset the `mcmc.list` with the `lapply` function.

The code below would trim off the first 50 samples from each chain.  You would just need to change `1:50` to something else if you wanted to trim more.

```
trimmed.posterior <- lapply(jags.object, function(df, vec){df[-vec,,drop=TRUE]}, 1:50)
```